# Azure Function App split between consumption plan and service app plan

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I've recently started working on a project in Azure Functions that has two components.
Both components use the same shared code, however the plans these components use seem to differ.

1. **An API endpoint** for web users for controlling objects saved in a CosmosDB - Would benefit from a **Service App plan** because of the cold/warm issues with Consumption plan.
2. **A backend scheduled process** that uses these objects - Would benefit from a **Consumption plan**, seeing as it could use automatic scaling, and exact execution time is not so important.

I thought of using the **premium plan** to solve both issues, but it seems pretty expensive (my workload is pretty low, and from the calculator on Azure's page it looks like around 150$ a month by default - correct me if I'm wrong).

I was wondering if there is a way to split a function app into two plans, or have two function apps share code.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create two function apps and hosts those accordingly based on your need. Regarding shared code --- its code which is compiled to binaries. So in that having shared code won't make any impact to be consumed by different function apps and deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to split a function app into two plans, or have two function apps share code.

The first options is not something that can be done. The second option is the one to go for here. You can have the shared code in a separate Class Library project and reference it from both Function Apps.

> A class library defines types and methods that are called by an application. If the library targets .NET Standard 2.0, it can be called by any .NET implementation (including .NET Framework) that supports .NET Standard 2.0. If the library targets .NET 5, it can be called by any application that targets .NET 5.
>
> When you create a class library, you can distribute it as a NuGet package or as a component bundled with the application that uses it.

More information: [Tutorial: Create a .NET class library using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio)

**EDIT:**
For Python, you can create modules.

> Python has a way to put definitions in a file and use them in a script or in an interactive instance of the interpreter. Such a file is called a module; definitions from a module can be imported into other modules or into the main module (the collection of variables that you have access to in a script executed at the top level and in calculator mode).

More info: [6. Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Python supports having re-usable code through [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant there is a special method for code reuse in Azure. Thanks.